# Simulate multiple MACs from a single physical Wi Fi adapter

Tags: wifi, simulation, wireless

For a simulation project, I am trying to simulate multiple MAC addresses from a single physical adapter. What I basically want is to send raw WiFi frames (both, data as well as management) for two virtual MAC addresses so that they both associate with a wireless AP. To the AP they should appear as if two different wireless devices/adapters (with different MAC addresses) have associated with it and are sending traffic. I just wanted to confirm if this seems feasible. I have achieved the same thing with wired LAN in the past but want to confirm the same for WiFi.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's feasible. Make sure the virtual MAC addresses aren't random but in an acceptable format - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address, otherwise the AP might reject the connection attempt.